# Translating ETL jobs from IBM Datastage to Apache Spark

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, datastage

It has been around 10 years that all of our ETL workloads are designed on IBM Datastage and Oracle as the database, but now, the enterprise is seeking options in **open source platforms** which offer **distributed parallel computing** to do the same tasks at lesser time and save some cost on technology as well.
I have never been a Java person all this while, however I have Python knowledge and I have also taken up formal training in Apache Spark, and I want to leverage this knowledge in translating our existing Datastage designs into Spark.
Given below are some of the common operations we are currently doing on all our Datastage jobs

1. read data from a flat file(txt/csv)
2. perform lookup (normal/range/sparse) on other small data tables
3. perform join with other LARGE tables
4. write data into a table
5. invoke a Siebel Enterprise Integration Manager to load data from one table to a Siebel table
6. extract data from multiple tables and create a SINGLE flat file(txt/csv)
7. ftp the file to a target server

Can all these operation be done from Spark?
**At least I am seeking to re create the steps #1, #2, #3, #4 and #6 in Spark, which(to the extent of my Spark knowledge) is achievable.**

Please help/redirect me to resources that will help in this regard.

Comment: Well written, but sorry, requests for recommendations are off-topic. StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

DataStage can run on Spark.  Talk with your IBM account representative.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.fd.doc/topics/t_config_spark.html